# Custom layer in sequential model tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to create a custom layer for my model, which can be used the classic Dense layer of Keras. Here my custom layer:

```
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel", 
                                      shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
                                      self.num_outputs])
    def call(self, input):
        return tf.matmul(input, self.kernel)
```

It does not do anything 'custom' for now.

But when I add it to my model

```
def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        MyDenseLayer(10)(normed_x_train),
        layers.Activation(tf.nn.relu),
        layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        ])
    return model
```

I get this:

```
The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: tf.Tensor(
[....])
```

Because probably I'm creating directly the object of class Custom Layer. But I do not find in the tf documentation how to add other properties to make it work as a normal layer, i.e. as something like `layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu)`

Is there a way to make it work like that ?

Comment: if u pass MyDenseLayer(10) instead of MyDenseLayer(10)(normed_x_train) ?

Comment: I get this: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()

Comment: try to make something with your model: predict/fit... for example: model(np.random.uniform(0,1, (10,30)).astype('float32'))

Comment: _Is there a way to make it work like that ?_ > That's what you're doing when subclassing. It inherits the behaviors of a Keras layer

Comment: @NicolasGervais sure, but I cannot use it as a normal Dense layer. I would like to just call it with the number of neurons, the activation function, and the input_shape if it is the 1st hidden layer

Comment: @MarcoCerliani actually I cannot define the model. When I define, that error appear

Comment: It works for me after implementing Marco's suggestion. Can you provide a fully copy-pastable example that makes the error? Otherwise we can't help

Comment: Then I'm surely doing something stupid. Tomorrow I'll give it another try and let you know, thanks!

Comment: Ok with model(np.random.uniform(0,1, (10,30)).astype('float32'))  the model has been built. But what now ? I mean could I have an activation paramater when I use my custom layer in the model ? and also, could I add the input_shape parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

As they were saying in the comments, do no introduce the input when defining the model. That is:

```
def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        MyDenseLayer(10),
        keras.layers.Activation(tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        ])
    return model
```

And then you can try:

```
model = build_model()
model(tf.random.uniform((100, 100)))
```

P.S: question has been laying around for days, but this was solved by @Marco Cerliani (I can delete it in any case)